# Buggy image resizing with CSS on Chrome, any way to fix it?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm displaying some favicons from external domains in my site. The problem is that when the favicon is anything different than 16px and I resize it the output is not always perfect. Randomly I get just the top or bottom half of the image, when I refresh suddenly the icon is displayed whole.

I have only experienced this problem in Chrome where it happens 90% of the time, I tested it on Firefox briefly and didn't seem to occur.

```
<style>
.icon {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
</style>

<img class="icon" src="http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://curiousphotos.blogspot.com/2010/07/creative-gizmos.html">
```

Is there a way to resize images without tearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are actually several methods,
1

```
<style>
.icon {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
</style>
```

2

```
<style>
.icon {
max-width: 16px;
max-height: 16px;
}
</style>
```

3

```
<img width="16" height="16" class="icon" src="http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://curiousphotos.blogspot.com/2010/07/creative-gizmos.html" />
```

I suppose #3 is more suitable for chrome

Comment: I accept since this includes all possible methods. However none fixes the issue, so it's a chrome bug

Answer (score 0):

May that can solve your problem:

```
<style>
    .icon {
    width: 16px !important;
    height: 16px !important;
</style>
```